# Bootstrap-saas not showing up glyphicons-halflings.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I am using bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.1), Now I upgraded my gem to  bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.1).

I am getting the following error :-

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_
```

Could you please help me how I can overcome this. I googled alot nothing worked.

1. Is there any proper steps to follow while upgrading from bootstrap-saas 2 to 3.1?
2. can I directly upgrade from 2 to 3?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3** switched from using bitmap icons (PNG) to **icon fonts**, so `glyphicons-halflings.png` are no longer in Bootstrap (hence the error): instead a set of icons is loaded as a font, each separate icon is placed using CSS classes with certain `font-family` and `content` (in a nutshell, in fact it's a bit more complicated).

**Migration from 2.x will be tedious**, that's for sure. In fact, there is [a migration guide on Bootstrap's official website](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) that hightlights most of the replacements you need to make, but there's quite a lot of breaking changes and enhancements, as the major version change suggests.